# Not able to query Child Components Directive/Component form Parent using ViewChild

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I am facing issue with querying a directive of the child component in a parent component
Table component uses scrollableView directive. and table component is used in my Report summary component.
in reportSummary component am trying to find the instance of scrollbaleView directive using @ViewChild.
I was able to find the table component using @ViewChild(DataTable) table : DataTable;
similarly, i should be able to find @ViewChild(ScrollableView) scrollview : ScrollableView;
but it does not
ViewChild documentation says this
https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild
You can use ViewChild to get the first element or the directive matching the selector from the view DOM. If the view DOM changes and a new child matches the selector, the property will be updated.
View queries are set before the ngAfterViewInit callback is called.

Interestingly table reference is not found in ngAfterViewInit function, i could get the value somewhere else.
But scrollableView is not found at any point in time.

### Expected behavior

scrollableView should also be queried and available.

### Minimal reproduction of the problem with instructions

https://stackblitz.com/edit/child-directive-query

Comment: I checked your stackblitz but I don't see where the ScrollableView is used in the template. Can you tell me? I am not familiar with Primeng, so I may have missed it.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the template of the `p-dataTable` component you will see that the `pScrollableView` is only loaded to the DOM if the `p-dataTable` is `scrollable`.

datatable.ts

```
<ng-template [ngIf]="scrollable">

  <div class="ui-datatable-scrollable-wrapper ui-helper-clearfix">

    <div *ngIf="hasFrozenColumns()" [pScrollableView]="frozenColumns" frozen="true"
         [headerColumnGroup]="frozenHeaderColumnGroup" [footerColumnGroup]="frozenFooterColumnGroup"
         [ngStyle]="{'width':this.frozenWidth}" class="ui-datatable-scrollable-view ui-datatable-frozen-view">
    </div>
    ...
</ng-template>
```

So you have to define your DataTable so that it uses the ScrollableView, otherwise it will not be in the DOM.

```
<p-dataTable [value]="cars" [loading]="loading" [scrollable]="true" scrollHeight="100px" >
```

Comment: thanks for the quick response. Your right i missed an example with scrollable, even with scrollable it is not able to fetch the scrollable view. Updated the example with scrollable.

Comment: How do you know that there should be the ScrollableView component. No scrollbar is shown. Have you seen it before in other code samples? [pScrollableView] is the selector for the component, but it does not show up in your sample on stackblitz.

Comment: @ zgue, Thanks for quick response, In the updated example scrollbar is visible in my example. and yes [pscrollableView] will get added.

Comment: can you check your stackblitz example, I could not see a scrollbar.

Comment: primeng css is not loaded, actually adding the in the angular-cli.json styles object should do that. but in stackblitz it is not working. Due to css un availability it is not showing the scrollbar visually, but scrollableview is added, you can observe that inspecting the elements

Comment: I have no working example yet but you can try to find the component with @ContentChild(ScrollableView) and log it on ngAfterContentInit()

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion zgue, i have tried this with no luck. I have update the stackblitz example with the this change.

Comment: Maybe you should open an issue on primeng github page.